# Apply a list of Boolean functions to two arguments in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monoids

I have a list of functions of type `a -> b -> Bool`, and am trying to apply them to two inputs and combine the results with `All` or `Any`.  I have this working with functions of one variable:

```
mconcat (map (All . ) [(<7),(>7),(==7)]) $ 6
```

but I cannot figure out how to do the same with two variable functions.

This works:

```
mconcat (map (All . ) (map (uncurry) [(<),(>),(==)])) $ (,) 6 7
```

but it looks to me like an ugly workaround.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sort of code that writes itself - you just have to make the types join up. But there are a couple of standard tools (namely `Applicative` and `Traversable`) which you can use to make your code shorter.

In the [`Data.Traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html) module lives `sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)`. When specialised to `[]`'s instance of `Traversable` and the function applicative `(->) r` we get:

```
sequenceA :: [r -> a] -> r -> [a]
```

So `sequenceA` yanks `->` out of `[]`, applying each function in the list to a fixed argument.

```
sequenceA [(< 7), (> 7), (== 7)] :: (Num n, Ord n) => n -> [Bool]
-- equivalent to:
\n -> map ($ n) [(< 7), (> 7), (== 7)]
```

So your first function can be written as

```
f :: (Num n, Ord n) => n -> Bool
f = and . sequenceA [(< 7), (> 7), (== 7)]
```

I'm using [`and`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:and) instead of `mconcat . map (All .)`.

For your second function, `uncurry` is the right tool. We have to map `uncurry` over the list of binary functions to get a list of unary functions of tuples, so that we can hoist the single argument out using `sequenceA`. Because `traverse f = sequenceA . map f` we can write it as:

```
g :: Ord n => n -> n -> Bool
g = curry $ and . traverse uncurry [(<), (>), (==)]
```

(NB, for any correctly-implemented instance of `Ord`, `>` and `<` should be mutually exclusive. So both of these functions will always return `False`.)

Answer (score 1):

A close alternative to the original code:

```
mconcat (map (\f a b -> All (f a b)) [(<),(<=)]) 3 4
```

One can further rewrite `\f a b -> All (f a b)` in pointless style:

```
mconcat (map ((.) (All .)) [(<),(<=)]) 3 4
```